# Extending the Application Class & Good Practices

Tags: android, singleton

I have been told recently that extending the Application Class in order to use it as a Singleton was a bad practice but without any explanation.
So what are the potentials problem behind the use of this class ? I have seen it used in many projects.

Also, if using the Application Class is a bad idea, what are the alternatives to store application level variables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using a Singleton class, as well as extending the `Application` class, is that if the application process is killed - which is very likely to happen when the app is left too long in background - the object will lose all your data.

However, using `Application` class may be a good option in cases when your app is in foreground or does not stay to much in background (although not 100% risk free).

As an alternative, you could save the data into `SharedPreferences`, or if your object is more complex, save it in a `database`.

Another option would be to combine both the use of `Application`, plus `SharedPreferences` for example. First try to retrieve the variable from `Application` instance, if the variable is null, then retrieve it from `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I will go for the hybrid approach. I am not a big fan of reading data from disk when it is avoidable.

Answer (score 7):

Using a Singleton approach is not really a bad idea, but it may be troublesome in the cases when being used in a multi-threaded environment where one thread sets a value to a variable and the other thread may over-write that value without any notice.

However, in order to keep application level instances/variables, it is suggested to **extend** `Application` class and define it in your **AndroidManifest.xml** as the default one. Since the application's context is created *only once* (till the application is running and stays in the memory) when you launch that application, so you may define some variables inside that class to make them availabe anywhere in your application's code using public methods.

Moreover, you may use your application class as *Singleton* too, since its guaranteed to be created only once when launched.

Comment: I used the singleton approach and that worked great for me. However, as you said, be careful in multi-threaded environments.